# Removing exceded pipes '|' in CSV after append files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, append

I have 3 dataframes. I need to convert them in one merged CSV separated by pipes '|'.

And I need to sort them by Column1 after append.

But, when I try to convert the final df to CSV, there comes exceeded pipes for null columns. How to avoid this?

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1': ['key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3'],
    'Column2': ['1100', '1100', '1100']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1': ['key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3', 'key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3'],
    'Column2': ['1110', '1110', '1110', '1110', '1110', '1110'],
    'Column3': ['xxr', 'xxv', 'xxw', 'xxt', 'xxe', 'xxz'],
    'Column4': ['wer', 'cad', 'sder', 'dse', 'sdf', 'csd']
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1': ['key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3', 'key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3'],
    'Column2': ['1115', '1115', '1115', '1115', '1115', '1115'],
    'Column3': ['xxr', 'xxv', 'xxw', 'xxt', 'xxe', 'xxz'],
    'Column4': ['wer', 'cad', 'sder', 'dse', 'sdf', 'csd'],
    'Column5': ['xxr', 'xxv', 'xxw', 'xxt', 'xxe', 'xxz'],
    'Column6': ['xxr', 'xxv', 'xxw', 'xxt', 'xxe', 'xxz'],
})

print(df1, df2, df3, sep="\n")

output = io.StringIO()

pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).sort_values("Column1") \
  .to_csv(output, header=False, index=False, sep="|")

print("csv",output.getvalue(),sep="\n")

output.seek(0)

df4 = pd.read_csv(output, header=None, sep="|", keep_default_na=False)

print("df4",df4,sep="\n" )

output.close()
```

***This is the output I have (note pipes'|'):***

```
key_1|1100||||
key_1|1110|xxr|wer||
key_1|1110|xxt|dse||
key_1|1115|xxr|wer|xxr|xxr
key_1|1115|xxt|dse|xxt|xxt
key_2|1100||||
key_2|1110|xxv|cad||
key_2|1110|xxe|sdf||
key_2|1115|xxv|cad|xxv|xxv
key_2|1115|xxe|sdf|xxe|xxe
key_3|1100||||
key_3|1110|xxw|sder||
key_3|1110|xxz|csd||
key_3|1115|xxw|sder|xxw|xxw
key_3|1115|xxz|csd|xxz|xxz
```

***But I need this without using regex (note pipes'|'):***

```
key_1|1100
key_1|1110|xxr|wer
key_1|1110|xxt|dse
key_1|1115|xxr|wer|xxr|xxr
key_1|1115|xxt|dse|xxt|xxt
key_2|1100
key_2|1110|xxv|cad
key_2|1110|xxe|sdf
key_2|1115|xxv|cad|xxv|xxv
key_2|1115|xxe|sdf|xxe|xxe
key_3|1100
key_3|1110|xxw|sder
key_3|1110|xxz|csd
key_3|1115|xxw|sder|xxw|xxw
key_3|1115|xxz|csd|xxz|xxz
```

Comment: The additional pipes for empty columns are expected and standard for CSV. Why do you want to remove them?

Comment: because i'm joining 3 tables with specific CSV format, that have to be sustained. not all columns are presented in each file and I need to preserve the original pipe format.

Comment: just to introduce, I will not work on this final data, I need to upload it to a specific database in the format I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this directly with `to_csv()`, if that's what you mean.

You can rewrite the csv output with something like `rstrip()`. Not sure what you meant by "without using regex" but python's `strip()` doesn't use regex.

```py
with io.StringIO() as output:
    pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).sort_values('Column1') \
      .to_csv(output, header=False, index=False, sep='|')
    
    output.seek(0)
    lines = [line.rstrip('|\n') for line in output]
    
    print('\n'.join(lines))
```

Output:

```
key_1|1100
key_1|1110|xxr|wer
key_1|1110|xxt|dse
key_1|1115|xxr|wer|xxr|xxr
key_1|1115|xxt|dse|xxt|xxt
key_2|1100
key_2|1110|xxv|cad
key_2|1110|xxe|sdf
key_2|1115|xxv|cad|xxv|xxv
key_2|1115|xxe|sdf|xxe|xxe
key_3|1100
key_3|1110|xxw|sder
key_3|1110|xxz|csd
key_3|1115|xxw|sder|xxw|xxw
key_3|1115|xxz|csd|xxz|xxz
```

Or with real files:

```py
output = 'output.csv'

pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).sort_values('Column1') \
  .to_csv(output, header=False, index=False, sep='|')

with open(output, 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip('|\n') for line in f]

with open(output, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines('\n'.join(lines))
```

Comment: Because those tables will probably change columns over time and I'm not sure "string" solutions will be flexible enough for this. But your solution is very interesting, I'll try to apply it. Thank you